# Timer sequence is messing up

Tags: c#, timer

So I am making a Robbery system the timer works perfectly on the first start but on second try it minuses the time 2ice.. meaning the sequence by the timer goes down is 10,9,8,7...... But on the 2nd try the sequence is 10,8,6,4...... on the 3rd try its 10,7,4,1..... Etc meaning on each start the timer sequence increase the decrease time? How is it possible?

```
public void robberyCountdown(User player)
{
    time = 10;
    cd.Elapsed += (source, e) => OnTimer(player);
    cd.Start();
}

public void OnTimer(User player)
{
    cd.Stop();
    cd.Elapsed -= (source, e) => OnTimer(player);
}
```

Comment: The way you are removing your event handler will not work. It doesn't know that the delegate you're trying to remove is equivalent to the one you added... you must store the delegate in a variable if you hope to remove it. Or, you could make a proper method out of it. So, what you currently have is multiple `Elapsed` handlers being added, and none being removed.

Comment: Also, if you are never actually using a *different* event handler, just set it once in your class initialization and don't worry about adding/removing it from the timer when you start and stop.

Comment: You're passing in anonymous functions to the eventhandler, so it isn't actually being removed. Try changing your definition of the `OnTimer` method to an event `(sender, source)`.

Comment: but when i use (cd1.Elapsed += (Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e, User player) on OnTimer it gives me an error on the cd.Elapsed -= (source, e) => OnTimer(source, e, player); Line stating local variable is source cannot be used here as it is defined in this scope

Answer (score 0):

Save the delegate you create into a private field so you can access it later:

```
private ElapsedEventHandler _onTimer;

public void robberyCountdown(User player)
{
    time = 10;
    _onTimer = (source, e) => OnTimer(player)
    cd.Elapsed += _onTimer;
    cd.Start();
}

public void OnTimer(User player)
{
    cd.Stop();
    cd.Elapsed -= _onTimer;
}
```

Of course, this approach assumes that `player` will be the same for both. A better way is probably to make your delegate just be constant, and use a private field to keep track of which players are being timed.

```
private HashSet<Player> _timedPlayers = new HashSet<Player>();

public MyClass() // or whatever your constructor is called
{
    cd.Elapsed += OnTimer;
}

public void OnTimer(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var player in _timedPlayers)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public void robberyCountdown(User player)
{
    time = 10;
    _timedPlayers.Add(player);
    cd.Start();
}

public void OnTimer(User player)
{
    cd.Stop();
    _timedPlayers.Remove(player);
}
```

Comment: iget this error  on the statement of cd.Elapsed += _onTimer;         Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler<System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs>' to 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler'

Comment: _onTimer has a red line stating that

Comment: i want the approach assuming it to be for the same player.